# Create flexible child div inside parent div

Tags: html, css

This is my Three divs.

```
<div class="header">
    <div>@ViewBag.Title</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

This is my CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .header
    {
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .content
    {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .footer
    {
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
</style>
```

Now I want that the  child div inside my parent Header div will be flexible. Whenever i change my browser size the child div inside the parent header div will also get resized according to my browser size. And will stay inside the header div. Please help.

Comment: there is no parent div or child div in your code

Answer (score 1):

```
.header div
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Use this for child div.

If set a child div's width is 50%. It filled in 50% of it's parent.

Comment: ,now i have a text inside the child div. I want the height of the text 100%, and it will also be flexible on browser change. How could i do that?

Comment: It take full height of it's parent. In your case .header has 10%

Comment: So is it possible that my text's height also i can set to 10% inside the parent header div?

Comment: If you want display large size of text use font-size.

Comment: I am using font-size but it is taking the text out of the parent header div. :(

Comment: If you use <div><p>text</p></div> this type, then you can write height of <p> is 10%.

Comment: Use media query in css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79790/discussion-between-amit-and-vignesh-bala).

Answer (score 0):

Do not set a height for the header element!

When dealing with responsive design, I try to avoid setting a height whenever possible. If you really need to set a height, do so on the child element, which then forces the header to have the height of its child.

Answer (score 0):

use this in ur css

```
display-inline:block:
```